# Quarkus ldap security authenticating with uid and description instad of userPassword

Tags: security, ldap, quarkus, elytron

I am using quarkus-elytron-security-ldap but in this user authentication is based on uid and description instead of userPassword. I was looking for property user_pssword_mapper where I can configure. COuld you please help on this topic?

I tried implementing quarkus-elytron-security-ldap. It worked for basic authentication where user and userPassword is provided. But now I want to authenticate on uid and description which I am not able to achieve.